# some issue while deleting the rectangle inside polygon

Tags: angular, fabricjs

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';
import { MountingTypeComponent } from './mounting-type/mounting-type.component';
import 'fabric';
declare let fabric;
@Component({
  selector: "app-custom-report",
  templateUrl: "./custom-report.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./custom-report.component.scss"]
})
export class CustomReportComponent implements OnInit {
  private canvas;
  private boundbox;
  private shapes = [];
  private shapeNoModuleZone;
  private shape2;
  private shapex;
  animal: string;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.shape2 = new fabric.Rect({
      width: 50,
      height: 100,
      fill: "green",
      left: 335,
      top: 305,
      lockRotation: true,
      hasControls: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
    });
    this.shapes.push(this.shape2);
  }
  openDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MountingTypeComponent, {
     height: '300px',
  width: '235px',
      data: { animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log("The dialog was closed");
      this.animal = result;
    });
  }
  deleteModule() {
    const activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
   // console.log(this.canvas.getActiveObject().left);
    if (this.canvas.getActiveObject()) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
        console.log(this.shapes[i].left, this.canvas.getActiveObject().left);
        if (
          this.canvas.getActiveObject().left ===
          this.shapes[i].left
        ) {

          console.log("both are equal");
          this.canvas.remove(this.canvas.getActiveObject());
         this.shapes.splice(i, 1);
         break;
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.shapes);
  }


  addModule() {
    this.shapex = new fabric.Rect({
      width: 50,
      height: 100,
      fill: "green",
      left: 335,
      top: 305,
      lockRotation: true,
      hasControls: false,
      perPixelTargetFind: true
    });
    this.shapes.push(this.shapex);
    console.log(this.shapes);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
      this.canvas.add(this.shapes[i]);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", {});
    console.log(this.canvas);
    this.boundbox = new fabric.Polygon(
      [
        { x: 0, y: -150 },
        { x: 250, y: -150 },
        { x: 250, y: 250 },
        { x: -150, y: 250 },
        { x: -150, y: 50 },
        { x: 0, y: 50 }
      ],
      {
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        angle: 0,
        fill: "lightgrey",
        selectable: false
      }
    );

    const text = new fabric.Text("No module zone", {
      fontSize: 30,
      fill: "white",
      left: 338,
      top: 115,
      selectable: false
    });

    this.shapeNoModuleZone = new fabric.Rect({
      label: "no module zone",
      width: 200,
      height: 100,
      fill: "red",
      text: "No module zone",
      left: 338,
      top: 95,
      selectable: false
    });

    let group = new fabric.Group([this.shapeNoModuleZone, text], {
      selectable: false
    });

    this.canvas.add(this.boundbox);
    for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.shapes[i]);
      this.canvas.add(this.shapes[i]);
    }
    //   this.canvas.add(this.shapeNoModuleZone);
    this.canvas.add(group);
    this.canvas.centerObject(this.boundbox);
  }
}
```

```html
       <div class="button-row">
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addModule()">Add Module</button>  
<button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="deleteModule()">Delete 
 Module</button>
<button mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog()">Type of mounting</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary">Panel Tilt</button>
<button mat-raised-button>Inter row distance</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent">Landscape vs Portrait</button>
<button mat-raised-button>Module Rating</button>
            </div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="430" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
```

On clicking of add module button, I am adding a new green rectangle inside polygon which can be drag and drop at any position, and after selecting a perticular rctangle, I am clicking on delete module button, and deleting the selected rectangle.
However, sometimes it works while sometimes it is not working, and when it is not working, I am getting an error like this.

Edit: after putting break, I got rid of that error, however it is still behaving the same way, i.e., sometime it does delete the rectangle while sometimes it do not. In this screenshot it didn't deleted the rectangle while it did compared the left value and found the same value too.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4gmT.png): [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
deleteModule() {
  const activeObject = this.canvas.getActiveObject();
  // console.log(this.canvas.getActiveObject().left);
  if (this.canvas.getActiveObject()) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.shapes[i].left, this.canvas.getActiveObject().left);
      if (this.canvas.getActiveObject().left ===this.shapes[i].left) 
      {

        console.log("both are equal");
        this.canvas.remove(this.canvas.getActiveObject());
        break;
        //  this.shapes.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(this.shapes);
}
```

In this function after removing the object from canvas `break;` the loop. The error coming because after removing `this.canvas.getActiveObject()` returns `null;`

```
addModule() {
  this.shapex = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 50,
    height: 100,
    fill: "green",
    left: 335,
    top: 305,
    lockRotation: true,
    hasControls: false,
    perPixelTargetFind: true
  });
  this.shapes.push(this.shapex);
  console.log(this.shapes);
  //for (let i = 0; i < this.shapes.length; i++) {
  //  this.canvas.add(this.shapes[i]);
  //}
  this.canvas.add(this.shapex);
}
```

While adding dont loop through all the shapes you stored to add it again in canvas just add the newly created object `this.canvas.add(this.shapex);` same inside `ngOnInit()`

Comment: after putting break, I got rid of that error however it is still  behaving the same way, i.e., sometimes it is working while sometimes it is not working.

Comment: I am not getting any error after putting break, however it is still behaving unpredictably, i.e., sometimes it does delete the rectangle while many times it is not deleting the rectangle while logic seems to correct as in the console i am getting those values which I am comparing i.e., 'left' value.

Comment: @HumbleDolt check other errors updated in answer. And still if you are not getting error, use debugger to find what you are missing.